# Blank java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have a problem with java applet.
I'm trying to make a simple java applet to see how it works.

When I put all in one class everything looks good, but when I divide it to other class the applet window show nothing:

first class:

```
package com.gmv.klinika;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Created by gumovvy on 27.11.14.
 */
public class mainClass extends JApplet {
    OtherClass fr = new OtherClass();
    public void init() {
        fr.guiInit();

    }

}
```

Second class:

```
package com.gmv.klinika;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created by gumovvy on 27.11.14.
 */
public class OtherClass extends JFrame {
    JButton jbtnOne;
    JButton jbtnTwo;

    JLabel jlab;
    public void guiInit() {
        // Set the applet to use flow layout.
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Create two buttons and a label.
        jbtnOne = new JButton("One");
        jbtnTwo = new JButton("Two");

        jlab = new JLabel("Press a button.");

        // Add action listeners for the buttons.
        jbtnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {
                jlab.setText("Button One pressed.");
            }
        });

        jbtnTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {
                jlab.setText("Button Two pressed.");
            }
        });

        // Add the components to the applet's content pane.
        getContentPane().add(jbtnOne);
        getContentPane().add(jbtnTwo);
        getContentPane().add(jlab);
    }




}
```

Do yo have any ideas?

-------EDITED-------

Original class look like this:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

/* 
This HTML can be used to launch the applet: 

<object code="MyApplet" width=240 height=100> 
</object> 

*/ 

public class MyApplet extends JApplet { 
  JButton jbtnOne; 
  JButton jbtnTwo; 

  JLabel jlab; 

  public void init() { 
    try { 
      SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable () { 
        public void run() { 
          guiInit(); // initialize the GUI 
        } 
      }); 
    } catch(Exception exc) { 
      System.out.println("Can't create because of "+ exc); 
    } 
  } 

  // Called second, after init().  Also called 
  // whenever the applet is restarted.  
  public void start() { 
    // Not used by this applet. 
  } 

  // Called when the applet is stopped. 
  public void stop() { 
    // Not used by this applet. 
  } 

  // Called when applet is terminated.  This is 
  // the last method executed. 
  public void destroy() { 
    // Not used by this applet. 
  } 

  // Setup and initialize the GUI.  
  private void guiInit() { 
    // Set the applet to use flow layout. 
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

    // Create two buttons and a label. 
    jbtnOne = new JButton("One"); 
    jbtnTwo = new JButton("Two"); 

    jlab = new JLabel("Press a button."); 

    // Add action listeners for the buttons. 
    jbtnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {      
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {  
        jlab.setText("Button One pressed.");  
      }      
    });      

    jbtnTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {      
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {  
        jlab.setText("Button Two pressed.");  
      }      
    });      

    // Add the components to the applet's content pane. 
    getContentPane().add(jbtnOne); 
    getContentPane().add(jbtnTwo); 
    getContentPane().add(jlab);     
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `JFrame` from `JApplet`?  This is counterintuitive and may actually violate security policies on many systems...Oh and you never make the `JFrame` visible.  My advice, drop the applet...

Comment: Were you looking to use something like `JPanel` instead of `JFrame` and actually add it into the applet's space?  Or are you trying to open a new window?

Comment: I'm trying to open a applet, finally it will be in browser but first, I want to make test in simple applet. I've changed a JFrame to JApplet and make it visible but still shows nothing. Even i try to put all instuction to constuctior but without effects.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"This is counterintuitive and may actually violate security policies on many systems."*  The biggest source of security problems in this scenarios is `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` since an applet (or frame launched from an applet) cannot shut down the VM (even if fully trusted).  The OP's frame sets no close operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `OtherClass` to extend from `JPanel` instead...

```
public class OtherClass extends JPanel {
    JButton jbtnOne;
    JButton jbtnTwo;

    JLabel jlab;
    public OtherClass() {
        // Set the applet to use flow layout.
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Create two buttons and a label.
        jbtnOne = new JButton("One");
        jbtnTwo = new JButton("Two");

        jlab = new JLabel("Press a button.");

        // Add action listeners for the buttons.
        jbtnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {
                jlab.setText("Button One pressed.");
            }
        });

        jbtnTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent le) {
                jlab.setText("Button Two pressed.");
            }
        });

        // Add the components to the applet's content pane.
        add(jbtnOne);
        add(jbtnTwo);
        add(jlab);
    }
}
```

Add `OtherClass` to `MainClass`...

```
public class MainClass extends JApplet {
    OtherClass fr = new OtherClass();
    @Override
    public void init() {
        add(fr);
    }

}
```

Conceptually, a `JAppelt` shouldn't be opening other windows, an applet should be self contained.  Because you can't add top level containers, like `JFrame`, to other containers, it makes for a poor choice to extend from, hence the reason why I choose to extend `OtherClass` from `JPanel` instead...

Comment: Thank You ! :) but your solution was uncompletlly. I added     OtherClass fr = new OtherClass();
    public void init() {
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.guiInit();
        add(fr);

    }

Comment: Compiles and runs just fine for me...Did you miss the changes to `MainClass` at the bottom of the post?  Swing components (with the exception of window based components) are visible by default...

Answer (score 0):

These lines look fishy:

```
    // Set the applet to use flow layout.
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ...

    // Add the components to the applet's content pane.
    getContentPane().add(jbtnOne);
    getContentPane().add(jbtnTwo);
    getContentPane().add(jlab);
```

If it was all in one class, setLayout() and getContentPane() would call the JApplet's setLayout and getContentPane methods, but not now as they're sitting in another class.

Could you post up how the code looked when it was all in one class?